jquery how to get element by name that comes from a variable, and check if element is hidden
I have a list of checkbox, with each checkbox element having a corresponding text input element. The text input is hidden initially. Upon clicking the checkbox, the corresponding text input will be visible allowing user to enter some value. Clicking checkbox again will make the text hidden and clear its value again.
The list is structured like this:
Each checkbox is named "options[33][]", and each checkbox has a different value, say 260, 261, 262, etc
Each corresponding text input is named "options_qty[33][260]", "options_qty[33][261]", "options_qty[33][262]", etc.
In script side, I need to refer to the text element that is corresponding to the checkbox that is being clicked and check if it's hidden or visible.
I tried this but it produces error:
$('input[name^="options[33]"]').click(function () { 
   var cval = $(this).val(); 
   var qname = "options_qty[33]["+cval+"]"; alert(qname);
   if ($('input[name=" + qname + "]').is(":hidden"))
   { 
         alert('off');
   } else {
         alert('on');
   }
};

As I can see, the qname was obtained correctly. But then the code errors out. What is the correct syntax to do this? And is(":hidden") correct for testing if it's hidden?
Thanks.

You need more quotes in there.  Right now, the "qname" is being literally passed to $, not its value.  So, $('input[name="' + qname + '"]').  See the extra quotes?

I tried with adding the extra quotes, still the same error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'is')

Oh sorry, it is correct! I just switched the two different quotes... single quote vs double quote, silly. And thank you!
